# Unable to run Get-AzRoleAssignment using AAD App (Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException)

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I have a requirement to get RBAC Roles from subscription using PowerShell. I'm trying to run **Get-AzRoleAssignment** using an AAD App Registration. I am able to connect to subscription but unable to get RBAC Roles. Can someone tell me what might be the problem with my app permissions.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the script you are running?

Comment: are you granting graph or old azure ad permissions?

Comment: rAJ
Here is my script

Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -ApplicationID $ApplicationID -Tenant $TenantID -CertificateThumbprint $CertificateThumbprint -SubscriptionID $SubscriptionID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding Admin Consent to **Azure Service Management** solved my issue

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Run the `Connect-AzAccount` command and log in with the tenant administrator or subscription administrator account.
2. Run the `Get-AzRoleAssignment` command.

[image]

Comment: Hello @Carl Zhao Actually it works with my UPN credentials. But I need to work for SPN connection as I need to automate this. I cannot automate with UPNs.

I am using below command
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -ApplicationID $ApplicationID -Tenant $TenantID -CertificateThumbprint $CertificateThumbprint -SubscriptionID $SubscriptionID